# How do I assign specific key events with mouse click events to this array of buttons in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating a virtual drum kit that uses specific external sound buttons that play for when a mouse event and key event are called. At the moment I have the mouse events working fine. I can't figure out how to add the specific key events (using T,R,P,O,E,I,U,W,Y,Q) to each button in the array. Testing the butt1 I have the issue of having t click the button before a key event is allowed. Here is my code:

```
   //initialise variables 

   //Array for buttons instances.
   var buttonsArray:Array = new Array();
   buttonsArray[0] = butt1;
   buttonsArray[1] = butt2;
   buttonsArray[2] = butt3;
   buttonsArray[3] = butt4;
   buttonsArray[4] = butt5;
   buttonsArray[5] = butt6;
   buttonsArray[6] = butt7;
   buttonsArray[7] = butt8;
   buttonsArray[8] = butt9;
   buttonsArray[9] = butt10;


   //Array for the sound clip names.
   var soundArray:Array = new Array();
   soundArray[0] = 't.mp3';
   soundArray[1] = 'r.mp3';
   soundArray[2] = 'p.mp3';
   soundArray[3] = 'o.mp3';
   soundArray[4] = 'e.mp3';
   soundArray[5] = 'i.mp3';
   soundArray[6] = 'u.mp3';
   soundArray[7] = 'w.mp3';
   soundArray[8] = 'y.mp3';
   soundArray[9] = 'q.mp3';

   //This function doesn't work as i have to click the symbol before I can 
   //use a key event. Same for all other buttons in the array. 
   butt1.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, tsymbolkeyhit);
   function tsymbolkeyhit(e:KeyboardEvent):void
   {
      if (e.keyCode == 84)
    {
        var s:Sound = new Sound();
        s.load(new URLRequest(soundArray[0]));
        s.play();
    }
   }



//playing acapella track with loading extertnal sound file
var my_sound:Sound = new Sound();
my_sound.load(new URLRequest("acapella.mp3"));
var my_channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
clicktoplaymusic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
function playSound(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    my_channel = my_sound.play();
}

//pausing the acapella track
pausebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);
function stopSound(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    my_channel.stop();
}

//custom mouse cursor;
Mouse.hide();

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveMouse);

function MoveMouse(Event)
{
    drum_stick.x = mouseX;
    drum_stick.y = mouseY;

}

//This adds the mouse click event to the buttons. 
for (var i:uint = 0; i < buttonsArray.length; i++)
{
        buttonsArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked);
}


//plays the sound file thats clicked.;
function buttonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < buttonsArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (e.target == buttonsArray[i])
        {
            var s:Sound = new Sound();
            s.load(new URLRequest(soundArray[i]));
            s.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You attached the `addEventListener` to `butt1`. Try using `this.addEventListener` instead?

Comment: Sorry  no that didn't work as I still have to click the button before I can use the key event...

Comment: Have you tried binding the event listener to the stage and put a simple switch in your KeyboardEvent-handler to handle the sounds? Also, both KeyboardEvent as MouseEvent extend from Event, so you could use that in your handler and use two switch cases so your code works both with keyboard as mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your keyboard event was bound to an object rather than the stage.  The stage receives these events, so you need to add the listener for the event there.

I've consolidated your code.  Notably, I've bound the button, sound filepath, and keystroke for each drum sound to the same index in your soundArray.  The advantage is, when you need to pair up a button/keystroke against the appropriate soundfile, your data is already together thereby making playback (and setup) much easier to maintain.

I can't test this now, and it was written freehand, so be sure to test.  Hope it helps.

-Cheers

```
// Replace the mouse with Drumsticks.
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveMouse);
Mouse.hide();
function MoveMouse(Event) {
    drum_stick.x = mouseX;
    drum_stick.y = mouseY;
}

// The array now holds the button objects, the filename, and the corresponding keys.
var soundArray:Array = [
    { "btn": butt1, "file": 't.mp3', "key": 84 },
    { "btn": butt2, "file": 'r.mp3', "key": 82 },
    { "btn": butt3, "file": 'p.mp3', "key": 80 },
    { "btn": butt4, "file": 'o.mp3', "key": 79 },
    { "btn": butt5, "file": 'e.mp3', "key": 69 },
    { "btn": butt6, "file": 'i.mp3', "key": 73 },
    { "btn": butt7, "file": 'u.mp3', "key": 85 },
    { "btn": butt8, "file": 'w.mp3', "key": 87 },
    { "btn": butt9, "file": 'y.mp3', "key": 89 },
    { "btn": butt10, "file": 'q.mp3', "key": 81 } ]

//This adds the mouse click event to the buttons. 
for each (var item:Object in soundArray) {
    item.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked);
}
// This was registered to a button.  It needs to be on the stage.
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, tsymbolkeyhit);

function tsymbolkeyhit(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    // Handles playing the sound when hitting keyboard buttons.
    for each (var item:Object in soundArray) {
        // If the key we hit matches the keystroke in the array, play the appropriate sound, and break the loop.
        if (item.key == e.keyCode) {
            playKey(item.file);
            break;
        }
    }
}

function buttonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // Handles playing sound when hitting onscreen buttons.
    for each (var item:Object in soundArray) {
        // If the button we clicked matches the button in the array, play the appropriate sound, and break the loop.
        if (item.btn == e.currentTarget) {
            playKey(item.file);
            break;
        }
    }
}

function playKey(filePath:String):void {
    // Simply plays the specified file.
    var snd:Sound = new Sound();
    var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
    snd.load(new URLRequest(filePath));
    channel = snd.play();
}

var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("acapella.mp3"));
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
clicktoplaymusic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);

function playSound(event:MouseEvent):void {
    myChannel = mySound.play();
}

pausebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);
function stopSound(event:MouseEvent):void {
    channel.stop();
}
```

Comment: @AnthonyDeal: In that case you should probably mark this as the accepted answer, to show that your question has been answered.

Comment: still getting an error on line 23 that I can't solve its this code part: //This adds the mouse click event to the buttons. 
    foreach (var item:Object in soundArray) {
    item.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked);
}

Comment: error states: "expecting an identifier before var" and expecting identifier before for. it also says that there are issues with the braces.. I hate AS3 sometimes!

Comment: It seems I forgot to add an end-brace to the array, and I also left a comma on the last line.  I've updated the code sample above.  AS3 isn't bad, especially when you enable debugging in the actionscript settings panel.  (don't code without it on; it's a lifesaver).

Comment: This is really annoying because I'm looking at it carefully and your code should work... really frustrating!

Comment: Awesome, you've nailed it! Thanks for your help!